# How to Obtain a Webpage's HTML Element Using Inspection For VBA Coding

Tags: html

> **Disclaimer:** The purpose of this question is to create a Q&A to be used as a reference for multiple questions, as opposed to explaining it many times.

How do I obtain a button or another object's HTML elements for IE automation in VBA?

Example: I am wanting to grab the "Post Your Question And Answer" button's element ID from [superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, we are using the popular Chrome Browser, although many other browsers have the same method for inspecting HTML elements.

## The Right-Click Method

1. Locate the element in question (in our case, the "**Post Your Question**" button).
2. Right-click the element
3. Chose the drop-down item `Inspect`

[image]

---

This will bring up the **F12 Developer Tools**. This toolbox will automatically highlight your element.

> [image]

As you can see, your element has a few options to reference it. The best method is using its `ID`, as this is always a unique value.

This element's ID is `submit-button-42`, which you found in this:

```htm
<id="submit-button-42">
```

In VBA, you can set a variable to this element by:

```vb
Dim IE As InternetExplorer, myElement As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
Set myElement = IE.document.getElementByID("submit-button-42")
```

---

Unfortunately, not every element has an ID. This element is included in a couple collections as well. The issue with collection items is that many other elements may also be included within that same collection - meaning that it's not a unique value.

In our example, there are two collections we can refer to: `class` and `tag`. The `ClassName` is **btn__with-icon**, which we see from:

```html
<button class="btn__with-icon"...>
```

and the `TagName` is **button** (which is listed directly before the class in the same example above).

In VBA, you can set a variable to these collections as such:

```vb
Dim IE As InteretExplorer, ieClassColl As Object, ieTagColl As Object
Set ieClassColl = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn__with-icon")
Set ieTagColl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
```

**Remember**, these are collection items. This means to reference our exact button in question, we either need to know its **index**, or we can loop with a `For...Each` statement

#### If you know the index # is **0**, then use that:

```vb
Set ieClassBtn = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn__with-icon")(0)
```

#### Otherwise, you can loop through them:

```vb
Dim o As Object, oColl As Object
Set oColl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each o In oColl
    If o.innerText = "Post Your Question And Answer" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```